# JavaScript CheckBox All

Tags: php, javascript

Pessoal preciso marcar todos os checkbox de meu sistema utilizando javascript, porem quero marcar os checkbox através do id, como faço isso? Estou fazendo dessa forma, porém não está funcionando:

```
function marcarTodos(marcar,cont){
    var id   = document.getElementById(cont);


        if(marcar){
            document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = 'Desmarcar Todos';
        }else{
            document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = 'Marcar Todos';
        }

        var i = 0;
        for(i=0; i<id.length;i++){

                id[i].checked = marcar;
        }
}
```

Comment: Você está usando Jquery ou precisa ser Javascript puro ?

Comment: Olá Lucas, estou usando js puro mas pode ser em ambos.

Answer (score 1):

O segundo o W3C, o `ID` é um atributo único por página.

> The id attribute specifies a unique id for an HTML element (the value must be unique within the HTML document).

Lei mais em: [HTML id Attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_id.asp)

Portanto, você deverá utilizar o NOME do checkbox ou uma classe para utilizá-los.

Abaixo, um exemplo funcional utilizando o nome para marcar ou desmarcar os checkboxes.

```js
function marcarTodos(nome, marcar){
    var id   = document.getElementsByName(nome);
    
    
        if(marcar){
            document.getElementById('acao').innerHTML = 'Clicou em marcar Todos';
        }else{
            document.getElementById('acao').innerHTML = 'Clicou em desmarcar Todos';
        }

        var i = 0;
        for(i=0; i<id.length;i++){
              
                id[i].checked = marcar;
        }
    }
```

```html
  <input type="checkbox" name="veiculo" value="Bicicleta"> Bicicleta<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="veiculo" value="Carro" > Carro<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="veiculo" value="Moto" > Moto<br>

<br/>
<button onclick="javascript:marcarTodos('veiculo', true);">Marcar todos</button>
<button onclick="javascript:marcarTodos('veiculo', false);">Desmarcar todos</button>

<div id="acao"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Utilizando Jquery você pode buscar todos os checkbox dentro de um determinado elemento (ou da página inteira) e checkar todos eles:

```
<html>

<div id="teste" />
<input type="checkbox" />
<input type="checkbox" />
<input type="checkbox" />
<input type="checkbox" />
<input type="checkbox" />
</div>
<button title="Marcar" id="marcar"> Marcar </button>
   <script>
    var marcado = false;
    $('#marcar').on("click", marcaChecks);

    function marcaChecks(){
    $('#teste').find('input[type=checkbox]').each(function(indice,elemento){
    elemento.checked = !marcado;
    });
    marcado = !marcado;
    }
</script>
</html>
```

Utilizei uma variável global para guardar se os checks deverão ser marcados ou desmarcados, se você inverter um a um como sugere a questão, no comentário você inverteria todos os checks.

[Link funcionando.](https://jsfiddle.net/scfdvc81/1/)